# VSCode reports issue with WxWidgets in Linux and MacOS

Tags: visual-studio-code, wxwidgets

I can't get VS Code to play nice with WxWidgets on Linux or MacOS. It seems like it's trying to default to MSW and gives an error (detailed below)

*The specific question is about VSCode (autocomplete, don't give false errors) with WxWidgets. In command prompt, compiling any Wx project works perfect.*

Steps:

VS Code is installed
-Create folder for project. Let's call it /src/hello
-Create a hello.cpp file with code from: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_helloworld.html
-Download WxWidgets into /src/hello/deps
-Going through steps to compile and install Wx https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/plat_osx_install.html
-Check my Intellisense includes to include ${workspaceFolder}/**
-Now, in the command prompt, if I run:

```
g++ hello.cpp 'wx-config --cxxflags --libs' -o hello
```

./hello runs perfect!

But in VSCode is unusable because it's giving me this error:

```
cannot open source file "../../../lib/vc_lib/msw/wx/setup.h" (dependency of "wx/wxprec.h")
```

I'm pretty sure msw is for windows?

I feel like I've tried everything:

-Downloaded and Git version of Wx (Yeah, I know it's the same. But people on the wx forums recommended trying...)
-Use the Homebrew WxWidgets install.
-Using the sample projects included with Wx.
-Using the Hello World
-Same issues in Linux and MacOS.
-Updating Intellisense's includes every way you can think of.
-Using the output of wxconfig and putting the cxxflags and lib include output into Intellisense.

Is anyone able to use VS Code on Linux or MacOS with the Hello World Wx example? If so what are your intellisense settings?

My properties:
[image]

*I'd rather not use Cmake for this.*

Comment: msw IS for Windows. What you need to do is open the project properties and add the include and lib folders as appropriate and then add the libraries you are linking with. You can run `wx-config --cxxflags` and `wx-config --libs` to find out exactly what you need. And get rid of everything you project currently has.

Comment: @Igor thanks for the reply! I've added a screenshot of my Intellisense props to make sure I have this correct. It seemed right to me but I'm obviously doing something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: as I said - run `wx-config --cxxflags` and `wx-config --libs` and you will see what to put in that compiler arguments window.

Comment: One more question - how exactly did you build wxWidgets? What was you configure line exactly?

Comment: @igor , Thanks for the reply again. I understand about the wx-config part. The spirit of me adding that image of properties was to see if you could tell me if I had them in the correct spot. To build wx I folldowed these steps exactly https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/plat_osx_install.html ... On my linux machine, I followed Wx's linux steps exactly. Wx is working great. It's VSCode that isn't.

Comment: lets solve the OSX part first. 1. Did you install the library? 2. If not - what is the directory where you put the source code?

Comment: Also, you include (`-I` option) is not complete. What is the output (in the Terminal) of: `wx-config --cxxflags`?

Comment: @Igor Yup. I installed the library. Output to of cxxflags is: -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-3.2 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXMAC__ -D__WXOSX__ -D__WXOSX_COCOA__

Comment: I've re-copied in wx-config output into my includes and still getting same error. Includes are now: 
-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-3.2 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXMAC__ -D__WXOSX__ -D__WXOSX_COCOA__

-L/usr/local/lib   -framework IOKit -framework Carbon -framework Cocoa -framework QuartzCore -framework AudioToolbox -framework System -framework OpenGL -lwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.2 -lwx_osx_cocoau_html-3.2 -lwx_osx_cocoau_qa-3.2 -lwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.2 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.2 -lwx_baseu_net-3.2 -lwx_baseu-3.2

Comment: `setup.h` file should be inside /usr/local/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-3.2. does it have it?and if it is - you should be getting a different error. Does VSCode generates the build output or it gives only `Compiling <file.name>.cpp`? If it does - can you post what it tries to run?

Comment: @Igor setup.h is in /usr/local/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-3.2/wx ... Possibly I need to add that folder to my includes. Currently isn't just {workspaceFolder}/** (you can see near the bottom of the image)

Comment: you should. That folder should be part of the output of `wx-config --cxxflags`.

Comment: @Igor adding that dir to includes didn't help. It's still saying "cannot open source file "../../../lib/vc_lib/msw/wx/setup.h" (dependency of "wx/wxprec.h")" ... Which means it's still looking for a MS windows setup.h for some reason?

Comment: yes, it is. How did you create a project? Maybe it is an VSCode install issue? Can you try to make a VM (brand new VSCode install and wxWidgets) and try again? If not - uninstall VSCode, install it again and make a brand new `empty` C++ project for Linux/GCC Makefile. I don't have this IDE, so just guessing here.

Comment: @Igor, VS Code works great with all other languages and frameworks I use. Go, PHP, Bash, Powershell, Dart, Flutter, etc. I didn't create a project. I just opened Code in an empty folder, created the files, it sensed C++ and had me update the Intenseness params. Also, since this is the same results on my Linux machine and MacOS machine, I don't think it's a bad install.

Comment: the only other thing I can suggest is to open a Terminal and do a grep for `msw` in the project folder. Since I don't use that IDE I can't give you a good instructions. But something is definitely problematic with your setup.